# How to deal with quote when using String.singleEscapeQuotes()

Tags: apex, string

I'm wondering about SOQL and String.singleEscapeQuotes().

I'm filling in a variable as: `String srchName = '%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchName) + '%';`

When I run the query `SELECT Id, Name FROM xxx WHERE Name LIKE :srchName` no row is fetch when the input is `"Paul's team"` because this input becomes `"Paul\'s Team"`.
How to remove the backslash added by String.singleEscapeQuotes() ?

Thanks,
Regards

Comment: The backslash is precisely what was added when you called `escapeSingleQuotes()`. Using a backslash before a character turns it into an _escape_ sequence (a way to tell the program that the escaped character is to be treated differently. The common example is `\n` which prints a **n**ew line instead of "n"). This is a rudimentary mechanism to avoid SQL injection (SOQL injection here on the SFDC platform).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use String.escapeSingleQuote when using bind variables. It is only meant to be used if you're using Dynamic Apex, and you are **not** using bind variables (variables in the query that start with `:`):

```
String searchTerm = 'bob\'s crab shack';
String query = 'SELECT Id FROM Something WHERE Name LIKE \'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchterm) + '%\'';
sObject[] records = Database.query(query);
```

If you're using bind variables, you don't need to worry about SOQL injection, it's impossible.

```
String searchTerm = 'bob\'s crab shack';
// Bind variables can never be "SOQL injected" and do not need escaped characters.
sObject[] records = [SELECT Id FROM Something WHERE Name LIKE :searchTerm];
```

---

```
String searchTerm = 'bob\'s crab shack';
String query = 'SELECT Id FROM Something WHERE Name LIKE :searchTerm';
sObject[] records = Database.query(query);
```

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm).

Comment: I'm using Database.query(query). My apologies to not have mentionned that

Comment: @learner You're still using `bind syntax`, though, correct? Do not mix String.escapeSingleQuotes with bind variables. Edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Right, I'll arrange my code in this way. Thanks a lot